# software (ddf1) raid problem after blown upgrade to 18.04 from 17.10

Tags: 18.04, dmraid

It appears something's gone to hell on my pair of mirrors which were ddf1 raid.

I can fsck all 17 filesystems with the live DVD image.

```
<pre>root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# dmraid -a y *
ERROR: ddf1: wrong # of devices in RAID set &quot;ddf1_disk1&quot; [1/2] on /dev/sdc
ERROR: ddf1: wrong # of devices in RAID set &quot;ddf1_disk0&quot; [1/2] on /dev/sde
ERROR: ddf1: wrong # of devices in RAID set &quot;ddf1_disk1&quot; [1/2] on /dev/sdb
ERROR: ddf1: wrong # of devices in RAID set &quot;ddf1_disk0&quot; [1/2] on /dev/sdd

root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# fsck -f -y  /dev/mapper/ddf1_disk1p5
fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
/dev/mapper/ddf1_disk1p5: 22780/524288 files (0.2% non-contiguous), 338335/2097152 blocks
```

The data's all there safe and sound it appears, but something in the Marvell bios raid configuration isn't matching up with reality on the system.

I'd like to avoid a full cpio or dump of each filesystem and a rebuild.

```
    root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# dmraid -s
    *** Group superset .ddf1_disks
    --> Active Subset
    name   : ddf1_disk0
    size   : 1953361280
    stride : 128
    type   : mirror
    status : ok
    subsets: 0
    devs   : 2
    spares : 0
    --> Active Subset
    name   : ddf1_disk1
    size   : 1953361280
    stride : 128
    type   : mirror
    status : ok
```

root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# dmraid -r
/dev/sdc: ddf1, ".ddf1_disks", GROUP, ok, 1953394096 sectors, data@ 0
/dev/sde: ddf1, ".ddf1_disks", GROUP, ok, 1953394096 sectors, data@ 0
/dev/sdb: ddf1, ".ddf1_disks", GROUP, ok, 1953394096 sectors, data@ 0
/dev/sdd: ddf1, ".ddf1_disks", GROUP, ok, 1953394096 sectors, data@ 0
/dev/sdf: ddf1, ".ddf1_disks", GROUP, ok, 1953394096 sectors, data@ 0

root@ubuntu:/etc# dmesg -T | grep sd
[Thu Apr 26 01:39:18 2018] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[Thu Apr 26 01:39:18 2018] sd 7:0:0:0: [sda] 30751744 512-byte logical blocks: (15.7 GB/14.7 GiB)
[Thu Apr 26 01:39:18 2018] sd 7:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[Thu Apr 26 01:39:18 2018] sd 7:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[Thu Apr 26 01:39:18 2018] sd 7:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't root@ubuntu:/etc# dmesg -T | grep sd
[Thu Apr 26 01:39:18 2018] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[Thu Apr 26 01:39:18 2018] sd 7:0:0:0: [sda] 30751744 512-byte logical blocks: (15.7 GB/14.7 GiB)
[Thu Apr 26 01:39:18 2018] sd 7:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[Thu Apr 26 01:39:18 2018] sd 7:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[Thu Apr 26 01:39:18 2018] sd 7:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[Thu Apr 26 01:39:18 2018]  sda: sda1
[Thu Apr 26 01:39:18 2018] sd 7:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
[Thu Apr 26 01:39:24 2018] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] 1953525168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
[Thu Apr 26 01:39:24 2018] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[Thu Apr 26 01:39:24 2018] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[Thu Apr 26 01:39:24 2018] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[Thu Apr 26 01:39:24 2018] sd 5:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[Thu Apr 26 01:39:24 2018] sd 5:0:1:0: [sdc] 1953525168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
[Thu Apr 26 01:39:24 2018] sd 5:0:1:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[Thu Apr 26 01:39:24 2018] sd 5:0:1:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[Thu Apr 26 01:39:24 2018] sd 5:0:1:0: [sdc] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[Thu Apr 26 01:39:24 2018] sd 5:0:1:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[Thu Apr 26 01:39:24 2018] sd 5:0:2:0: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 0
[Thu Apr 26 01:39:24 2018] sd 5:0:3:0: Attached scsi generic sg5 type 0
[Thu Apr 26 01:39:24 2018] sd 5:0:2:0: [sdd] 1953525168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
[Thu Apr 26 01:39:24 2018] sd 5:0:3:0: [sde] 1953525168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
[Thu Apr 26 01:39:24 2018] sd 5:0:3:0: [sde] Write Protect is off
[Thu Apr 26 01:39:24 2018] sd 5:0:3:0: [sde] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[Thu Apr 26 01:39:24 2018] sd 5:0:3:0: [sde] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[Thu Apr 26 01:39:24 2018] sd 5:0:2:0: [sdd] Write Protect is off
[Thu Apr 26 01:39:24 2018] sd 5:0:2:0: [sdd] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[Thu Apr 26 01:39:24 2018] sd 5:0:4:0: Attached scsi generic sg6 type 0
[Thu Apr 26 01:39:24 2018] sd 5:0:2:0: [sdd] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[Thu Apr 26 01:39:24 2018] sd 5:0:4:0: [sdf] 1953525168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
[Thu Apr 26 01:39:24 2018] sd 5:0:4:0: [sdf] Write Protect is off
[Thu Apr 26 01:39:24 2018] sd 5:0:4:0: [sdf] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[Thu Apr 26 01:39:24 2018] sd 5:0:4:0: [sdf] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[Thu Apr 26 01:39:24 2018] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[Thu Apr 26 01:39:24 2018] sd 5:0:1:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
[Thu Apr 26 01:39:24 2018] sd 5:0:2:0: [sdd] Attached SCSI disk
[Thu Apr 26 01:39:24 2018] sd 5:0:3:0: [sde] Attached SCSI disk
[Thu Apr 26 01:39:24 2018]  sdf:
[Thu Apr 26 01:39:24 2018] sd 5:0:4:0: [sdf] Attached SCSI disk
support DPO or FUA

I can mount and fsck the /dev/mapper/ddf1_disk1p# partitions fine

```
root@ubuntu:/# mount /dev/mapper/ddf1_disk1p5 /mnt
root@ubuntu:/# ls /mnt
System.map-4.13.0-38-generic  initrd.img-4.15.0-15-generic
System.map-4.15.0-15-generic  lost+found
abi-4.13.0-38-generic         memtest86+.bin
abi-4.15.0-15-generic         memtest86+.elf
config-4.13.0-38-generic      memtest86+_multiboot.bin
config-4.15.0-15-generic      retpoline-4.13.0-38-generic
grub                          vmlinuz-4.13.0-38-generic
initrd.img-4.13.0-38-generic  vmlinuz-4.15.0-15-generic


root@ubuntu:/# df /mnt
Filesystem               1K-blocks   Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ddf1_disk1p1    999320 179752    750756  20% /mnt
root@ubuntu:/#
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Bill

Comment: Good thing you made a boot-drive backup first.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help you but try to use this https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/  , i manage to fix my raid0 boot on ubuntu 16.04 i don't know if it will work on 18.04. Right now i want to upgrade  from 16.04 to 18.04 i hope it will not blow my raid0 boot

Comment: It fixes some problems but the RAID seems to require manually running `dmraid -ay`.